# Show that a matrix $A$ is positive definite in $\mathbb{C^2}$ under some conditions

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Prove that the matrix $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}2+a & -1\\-1 & 2+a\end{bmatrix}  $$ is positive definite in $\mathbb{C^2}$ for any $a > -1$

If the question had been posed to show positive definiteness in $\mathbb{R^2}$, I would have had no problem. However, I have never worked in the complex plane, and we have never really talked about it in class, so I'm grasping for ideas with no idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What definition of "positive definite" is your class using?

Comment: Have you learned of any of the spectral theorems? The real one says symmetric matrices are positive semi-definite, the complex one say that hermitian matrices are positive semi-definite.

Comment: @J.M.  We say $A$ is positive definite when $x^TAx > 0$ or when $(Ax, x) >0$

Comment: @mathreadler  I believe we have yes... could I say that since this matrix is symmetric for any $a$, it is also technically hermitian. then say that when $a > -1$ this matrix will be strictly diagonally dominant which implies positive definite?

Comment: you can use symmetricity / hermitanicity to conclude all eigenvalues must be $\in \mathbb{R} , \geq 0$ then what is left to do is to rule out $=0$ possibility. ( Assuming you have learned of eigenvalues ).

Comment: Yes you can also use diagonal dominance, but the matrix will be symmetric and non degenerate also if $a<-1$, $a \neq -3$.